How to break y axis after using ax2.twinx()
I have created a plot with two y axis using ax2.twinx(). But now i want to break y axys according to a certain value to create two different sublots with an interval of value between them.
How to do so? Here is my code:
# Plot 2: Home range amplitude
sns.lineplot(data=home_range_df, x='month1', y='HUP', hue='Tag', ax=ax2, legend=True, palette=palette19)
# Create a secondary y-axis
ax2_right = ax2.twinx()
# Plot the mean home range amplitude with error bars on the secondary y-axis
ax2_right.errorbar(home_range_mean_df['month1'], home_range_mean_df['mean'], yerr=home_range_mean_df['sem'], fmt='o', color='gray', alpha=0.5, capsize=5)
# Plot the mean home range amplitude on the secondary y-axis
sns.barplot(data=home_range_mean_df, x='month1', y='mean', ax=ax2_right, alpha=0.5, color='blue')

ax2.set_title('')
ax2.set_xlabel('Date')
ax2.set_ylabel('Habitat Usage Potential m2 (Individuals)')
ax2_right.set_ylabel('Mean Habitat Usage Potential m2')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


Did you consider using a log scale for the y-axis? That might be easier to interpret than a broken axis. With twin axes, everything becomes even more messy.  Also note that on StackOverflow, reproducible code and test data are a requirement.
